# how to find right version of bson from pip for pymongo/mongoengine

Tags: pymongo, mongoengine, bson, flask-mongoengine

I am working on a (python 2.7) flask-mongoengine application which uses bson's ObjectId. The project requires bson in one or another way. I don't have root access on the host i'm trying to deploy the application and pip install bson fails:

```
-bash-4.1$ pip install bson
Collecting bson
 Using cached bson-1.1.0.tar.gz
  Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/tmp/pip-build-BBOawV/bson/setup.py", line 24, in <module>
    import bson
   File "bson/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from . import codec
   File "bson/codec.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .objects import *
   File "bson/objects.py", line 36
    class BSONObject(object, metaclass=ABCMeta):
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-BBOawV/bson/
```

On the other hand, https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/installation.html states that i shouldn't use this version of bson and rely on pymongo's implementation. However, on my computer where I have pymongo-3.2.1 installed, I cannot import pymongo.objectId - so what am I doing wrong and how can I get bson to work with my setup?

Thank you soo much!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and re-installing PyMongo fixed the BSON dependencies:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pymongo
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

Just download the tarball from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bson/0.4.3
and do a manual install:

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: +1 for this - I should have probably added -- if I put bson==0.4.3 in my requrements.txt file, I can do the pip install. However, in the bson help it says:
The following types are unsupported, because for data exchange purposes, they're
    over-engineered:
        ....
        0x07 (ObjectId)
        ....
so while it is a way to get a valid bson version via pip, it doesn't really solve the problem.

Comment: As per the package documentation:
"This bson package is designed for Python 3, and will not work with Python 2!"
[bson 1.1.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bson/1.1.0)

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have root access and can't install a distribution version of bson, I chose to drop the object in my DB document definition. 
This solves it for me, since it's also cleaner but the truth is as Mihai stated: pip install bson seems to be limited to python3 projects.